# Remove quotes from parameterized query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm using postgresql and ruby on rails and I'm trying to parameterize my query but when I do, it adds quotes on the params filling my place holder. Here's a simple example:

```
query = <<-SQL
   select * from table1 ?
SQL
```

When I execute the above query like this:

```
result = Table1.find_by_sql([query, "where table1.locations IN (1,2,3)"])
```

It will execute the query like this with the quotations around the condition:

```
select * from table1 'where table1.locations IN (1,2,3)'
```

But I want:

```
select * from table1 where table1.locations IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: That is __exactly__ what parametrization does: prevent arbitrary SQL injection. https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind parts of the query like that, only values. If you want to have a dynamic `where` clause you'll have to resort to string concatenation:

```
result = Table1.find_by_sql([query + " where table1.locations IN (1,2,3)")
```